# Can't exclude folders for VS Code OmniSharp's Code Analyser

Tags: visual-studio-code, roslyn-code-analysis, omnisharp

I use **VS Code** with **Unity** and I'm trying to **ignore the code analysis of third party code bases**.

I've read [OmniSharp's github page](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/wiki/Configuration-Options#file-options), and tried excluding those folders but I failed to do so. What I did was:

I've created an `omnisharp.json` file where the `.csproj` files are, with this content:

```
{
    "fileOptions": {
        "excludeSearchPatterns": [
            "Assets/ThirdPartyFolder/**/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `systemExcludeSearchPatterns` instead of `excludeSearchPatterns` but to no avail.

(And also tried adding the `"/**/*"` path for fun, but still everything was analyzed. :\ )

I always restarted OmniSharp after changing the json file:

[image]

But the "want-to-be-excluded folders" are still analyzed.

Like after I added `"Assets/AltUnityTester/**/*"`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create `.editorconfig` file in your project root folder with the following content:

```
root = true

[Assets/Assetstore/**.cs]
generated_code = true
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none

[Assets/Plugins/**.cs]
generated_code = true
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none
```

My `omnisharp.json` located in the project root folder:

```
{
    "RoslynExtensionsOptions": {
        "EnableEditorConfigSupport": true,
        "EnableAnalyzersSupport": true,
        "LocationPaths": [
            "./NuGet/microsoft.unity.analyzers.1.12.0"
        ]
    }
}
```

This solution works for me. See [Enabling Unity warnings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity#_enabling-unity-warnings).

C# for Visual Studio Code: v1.24.1